# PHP str_replace to replace numbers with words

Tags: php, str-replace

I have a website that needs to display phone numbers to users, but rather than display the actual number for someone to harvest from the source code, I'd like to replace each digit of the phone number with the corresponding word.  For instance...

```
355-758-0384

Would become

three five five - seven five eight - zero three eight four
```

Can this be done?  Sorry, I don't have any code to display because I don't even know where to start with this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$string="355-758-0384";
$search  = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
$replace = array('zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine');
echo str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
```

Then you can use any different string aswell without having to update code

Edit:

And if you want automatic spaces on the end then your $replace array can be

```
$replace = array('zero ', 'one ', 'two ', 'three ', 'four ', 'five ', 'six ', 'seven ', 'eight ', 'nine ');
```

Comment: Thanks  I ended up editing a little to space out the words and added some spacing for the dashes as well.  This was very concise and effective.

Answer (score 1):

```
str_replace('  ', ' ', strtr($phone_number, array(
  '0' => ' zero ',
  '1' => ' one ',
  ...
)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '355-758-0384';
$numbers = array(
  '0' => 'zero',
  '1' => 'one',
  '2' => 'two',
  '3' => 'three',
  '4' => 'four',
  '5' => 'five',
  '6' => 'six',
  '7' => 'seven',
  '8' => 'eight',
  '9' => 'nine',
);
$string = preg_replace_callback( '/[0-9]/', function ( $matches ) use ( $numbers ) {
  return $numbers[ $matches[0] ];
}, $string );
```

After trying other the solutions first, I'm using this one as it's more performant.  I assumed a non-regex solution would be faster, but not in this case.

My tests using 10k interations on PHP 7.0.28:

```
preg_replace_callback  0.00643s
str_replace w/strtr    0.01015s  57% slower
str_replace w/arrays   0.01123s  74% slower
```

For the spaces around the dash:

`$string = str_replace( '-', ' - ', $string );`